# Why does this python program not work in IDLE, when using a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, i2c

The following code communicates with multiple pH modules, via the serial port.  The pH modules are selected via a multiplexer via the i2c bus using an 8574N chip. When the raspberry pi has booted up the program works correctly in the terminal however, if the program was to be stop and be restarted it fails to initialize correctly.  Also, this program does not work correctly in the python IDLE (selecting random devices on the multiplexer).   It seems like the i2c or serial comms on the pi is not initializing correctly. For example, in IDLE when selecting a module, It brings up the incorrect module to the one that you have chosen spits out incorrect data. However, this all works fine in the terminal.

Does any one have any ideas??

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
from smbus import SMBus
# from itertools import cycle
import time
import serial

usbport = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
ser = serial.Serial(usbport, 9600, timeout = 2)#
line = ""
data = ""
bus = SMBus(1) # Port 1 used on REV2 
print "Electronics Workshop PH Reader."
print "=========================="
global count
count = 0 #init count to 0
probevalue = ""



def inputsel(count):
   bus.write_byte(0x38, 0x00)
   # count = input(" Select ph unit '0 to 23'") # count now incremented during program
   count = input(" Select ph unit '0 to 23'")
   if (count< 16):
      data_sel = count
      data_sel = data_sel | 32 # or the 2 numbers together

   else:
      data_sel = count - 16
      data_sel = data_sel | 16 # or the 2 numbers together  


   bus.write_byte(0x38, data_sel) # send "count"Varable out to I2c Bus
   print str(data_sel)
   time.sleep (1) 
   data_sel = 0
   print "Reading Channel:" + str(count)

def write_serial(serial_data):
    global ser    
    data = ""
    line = ""
    status = ""
    ser.write(serial_data) # set ph unit to take one reading at a time 
    ser.write("\r") # set ph unit to take one reading at a time
    time.sleep (1)   
    ser.write(serial_data) # set ph unit to take one reading at a time 
    ser.write("\r")
    time.sleep (1)
    while status != "done":
            data = ser.read(1) # gets data from PH module '     
            if(data == "\r"): # check each bite of data to see if its a carriage return expecting "XX.XXr"
                    #carriage return sent diplay message and data 
                    print "Received from sensor:" + line
                    status = "done"
                    probevalue = line
                    line ="     "
                    ser.flushInput()
                    ser.flushOutput()
            else:
                    # all 5 bytes of data have not been received
                    line = line + data # add one to the varable line
                    #if(data == " "):
                     #       write_serial()

    return probevalue

def main():
      global serial_data
      serial_data = " "
      global count
      probevalue = " "
      count = 0
      bus.write_byte(0x38, 0)
      while 1:

         inputsel(count) #select the input based off count variable
         loop = range(0,7) 
         for loopcount in loop:
            if ((loopcount == 0) | (loopcount == 1)): #set command to #?
               serial_data = "#?\r" #set command to request id
               if (loopcount == 0): #if buffer needs clearing
                 print "Clearing Buffer....."                 
               else:  print "Requesting ID....."
               probevalue = write_serial(serial_data) #call write_serial with #? command put value into probevalue


            elif (loopcount >= 2): #set r command once buffer clear and ID obtained
               serial_data = "r\r"  #set command to read value
               if (loopcount == 2): print "Reading pH:" #output reaidng pH when loopcounter at 2
               probevalue = write_serial(serial_data) #call write_serial with r command put value into probevalue

         print "=========================="
```

Comment: For starters you want to check that the USB port is actually the same on both systems.

Comment: You need to elaborate more on `fails to initialize correctly.` and `does not work correctly`. What does this mean, exactly?

Comment: @shuttle87 Thank you for your prompt reply.  Is there an initialization routine that I can use for the serial port and the i2c at the start of the program.  Also, could you please elaborate on the USB answer? slightly confused as i am using serial comms on the raspberry pi.

Comment: @That1Guy Thanks for your response.  It seems like the i2c or serial comms on the pi is not initializing correctly. For example, in IDLE when selecting a module, It brings up the incorrect module to the one that you have chosen spits out incorrect data.  However, this all works fine in the terminal....

Comment: @OzMac That's an interesting problem. You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32206557/edit) that into your question.

Comment: `usbport = '/dev/ttyAMA0'` this is the port on the raspberry pi. When you run your code with IDLE I presume that is done from a different environment. Is the usb port the same in the environment that IDLE is running in?